# Scala List - extract 'Date' and 'Adj close' values (columns)

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I am trying to extract the 'Date' and 'Adj close' columns

```
List(Date,    Open,       High,    Low,      Close, Volume, Adj Close
2016-11-10, 113.50, 115.440002, 111.50, 113.120003, 5700, 113.120003
2016-11-09, 113.00, 118.00,     113.00, 117.419998, 4000, 117.419998
2016-11-08, 118.139999, 120.129997, 115.07, 118.239998, 1900, 118.239998
```

I have tried putting all values into a 2D array so for each row i could just get column 0 and column 6 which would achieve my goal, however due to being new to Scala i was unable to achieve that.

Is there a more simple way of achieving this?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What form/type is the data before you tried to put it in "a 2D array"? Where is your data coming from? Are you reading it from a file?

Comment: just convert your Array into a DataFrame, then you can select columns the same way you'd do it in SQL.
Even easier would be to simply read your data directly into a DataFrame.

Answer (score 0):

```
[your list variable here].map(e => (e._1, e._7))
```

will give you a list of tuples with the first and last element.